# having a problem with octave on vector dimensions

Tags: vector, octave

i keep getting this error on octave,
error: operator *: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x101, op2 is 1x956)
error: called from
whateverson at line 11 column 5

the program is as follows

```
% Power flow
clear all;
clc;
V1 = 0.95*238:0.001*238:1.05*238; %kV
V2 = 0.95*23:0.001*230:1.05*230;%kV
D_angle = 15 * (pi / 180); % Radians
R = 230 * 0.099; #Ohm
X = 230 * 0.518;  #Ohm

% Equations:
P12 = (1 / (R^2 + X^2)) * (R .* V1.^2 - R .* V1 * V2 .* cos (D_angle) + X .* V1 * V2 .* sin(D_angle));
Q12 = (1 / (R^2 + X^2)) * (X .* V1.^2 - X .* V1 * V2 .* cos (D_angle) - R .* V1 * V2 .* sin(D_angle));

P21 = (1 / (R^2 + X^2)) * (R .* V2.^2 - R .* V1 * V2 .* cos (D_angle) - X .* V1 * V2 .* sin(D_angle));

Q21 = (1 / (R^2 + X^2)) * (X .* V2.^2 - X .* V1 * V2 .* cos (D_angle) + R .* V1 * V2 .* sin(D_angle));

Ploss = P12 + P21;
Qloss = Q12 + Q21;

clf (figure (1));
figure(1);
    plot (V1,P12, 'b');
    xlabel('V1(kV)');
    ylabel('P12 (MW)');
    box on;
    grid on;

apparently my vectors dont have the same dimensions but i just cant get why, some light would be much appreciated
```

Comment: You have `V1 * V2`. `V1` is 1x101 and `V2` is 1x956. Those don't match

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, the error is here:

```
V2 = 0.95*23:0.001*230:1.05*230;%kV
```

You forgot a "0"

```
V2 = 0.95*230:0.001*230:1.05*230;%kV
```